# Java - Trouble with implementation

Tags: java

So, I was watching a tutorial on how to make a basic 2d game in java, but at one point in the tutorial he told us to implement KeyListener. When i tried to do this is gave me this error which i cannot find a solution to.

Error message -

```
java: "PackageName"."ClassName" is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent) in java.awt.event.KeyListener
```

And here is my code -

```
package Classes;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
class Data extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    static int x = 225;
    static int y = 200;
    public Data(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        repaint();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Data game = new Data();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        frame.setTitle("Game");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm coding in Java 1.7
Does any one know how to fix the implementation error? Thanks.

Comment: Well do you understand the error message? Why did you write `implements KeyListener` if you didn't actually want to provide any of the `KeyListener` methods? Do you understand what it means to implement an interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write a class that implements another class you must 'implement', or in other words, write all the required methods that the other class requires or you will end up with these implementation errors.

If you don't understand this, I highly suggest that you read the [Implementing an Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) page on the Oracle site.

For your specific case, from the [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) javadoc, we can see that you will be required to implement:

```
void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
```